# Why are my breakpoints not being hit when debugging Google Unit Test with LLDB in Visual Code C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, googletest, lldb

I am using LLDB to debug my Google Unit Test binary in Visual Code. I have added debug breakpoints in the Debug console[image]

But the test executes without waiting at any of the breakpoints. What am I missing?

This is what my launch.json looks like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [    
      {
        "name": "gtest",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/Users/rashmii/Documents/cpp_project/bazel-bin/src/leet_test",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
    }        
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I recommend to use the codelldb extension and then specify type as lldb. Cppdbg is used when you use the shipped debugger backend that communicates over MI.. but that I hear isn't maintained and only works reliable with gdb. Codelldb works fine.

Comment: I use CodeLLDB extension:
`"type": "lldb",`

Comment: Some test extensions (like TestMate IIRC)  generate a launch.json dynamically and don't use yours if you click their "debug" icon. TestMate has a setting that you can assing a json-map with content that is largely equivalent to a launch.json content, which worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried using CodeLLDb but the execution still falls through. I am writing Google Unit Tests and building them with Bazel. Is that related to why the breakpoints are not being respected?